# A top-down video game from early 2000s or earlier, in which you can absorb defeated foes with a straw to replenish your health

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This is some kind of video game I barely saw being played on a computer between 1998 and 2004 (although it could have been released earlier).

The game featured a kind of top-down view, but not like GTA 1 nor GTA 2; a bit more like Zelda 1 (not the graphics but the "camera" angle; the GTAs also show you the characters and vehicles from the top, whereas the Zelda game shows Link as if you are standing in front of him). None of this was 3D, as far as I can remember.

Gameplay wise, I think everything happened on some kind of desert looking map, and you had to reach the end of the level to proceed. You can control creatures, each of which could pick up a melee weapon to fight or carry something. I remember them as being "worms" from the Worms series of video games, but I was not able to find the game by searching the entire series, and the gameplay doesn't seem to fit the Worms series either.

Some weapons were more effective than others. I think 2 of the strongest weapons (at this point of the game at least, very early on) were a golf club and a wooden club.

To reach the end, you had to kill the enemies creatures. I can't remember if they moved around, although I remember one distinct memory where one of them was blocking the only path to the end of the level. The creature was armed with a golf club, and he was hitting so hard that the creatures we sent against it kept dying one after another.

The game worked on some kind of "turn by turn" basis. When two enemy units are next to each other, they start fighting. The first one would land a hit before the other did.

There was a very thin looking health bar displayed above the creatures to let us know how much health they had left. Whenever an enemy was defeated, I think they turned into a soupy puddle. You could order one of your units to drink it up to replenish some health, and they did so by pulling out a straw to absorb it entirely.

Besides weapons, I think you could also order your units to pick up some kind of green plate. The unit carrying it was weaponless and defenceless, which means it could not fight back if attacked. There was one plate per level I think, and when you carried it to the end, it added up to something like a piece of a puzzle that should assemble to represent something; a planet or a medallion maybe?

Comment: Probably Gruntz

Comment: @Yorik You know what? That's very possible. May I suggest you to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[User Yorik](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/42056/yorik) suggested a game in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278621/a-top-down-video-game-from-early-2000s-or-earlier-in-which-you-can-absorb-defea#comment768558_278621), and after looking at some playthrough videos, I can confirm the game I was looking for is indeed *[Gruntz (1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruntz)* as suggested.

Graphically speaking, the game does fit the overall description I remembered: top-down, "desert-looking" even if it isn't exactly how I remembered it, and the creatures can pick up weapons to fight, including a wooden club.

Gameplay-wise, in the Youtube video above, you can see some creatures fighting as soon as they get into contact at the 1:10 mark. One of the player's creature is using a wooden club, and the enemy (in purple) is using a straw. The instant the enemy creature dies, he turns into a puddle.

[image: A screenshot showing some creatures fighting in the game. One is fighting with a club, and the purple one is carrying what seems to be a red and white stripped straw.]

[image: The defeated purple enemy turns into a puddle.]

At 1:35, one of the creatures pick up something, which fills up an empty circle in the interface on the right, and the creature picking it up can be seen carrying it. According to Wikipedia:

> A quest is where the player has to puzzle out how to get a grunt to the Warpstone, and then bring that Grunt to the King.

Which also fits the part I remembered where we can pick up something and bring it to the end of the map.

[image: One of the creatures pick up the stone and carries it, as it is added into the empty circle on the right side of the interface.]

And the following video has the aforementioned straw scene from the question at 4:02. The orange creature, after taking damage from fighting against a purple creature, proceeds to drink the yellow puddle nearby, before proceeding to drink the purple puddle left by the defeated creature:

[image: The orange creature is drinking up the yellow puddle to regenerate energy, using a red and white stripped straw, while the vanquished purple enemy is turning into puddle.]

[image: The orange creature proceeds with drinking the purple puddle from the former purple creature.]